# Combining queries into one result (rest_views)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I need to combine a different "order_by" value, and a different "distinct" value.

I believe this is a limitation of Postgres. So am trying to do this with two different queries.

In English- I want it to work like this:

1 (qset1)- GET a list of PK's (high number of them (500), as many will be duplicates)

2 (qset2)- Make sure all the PK's are unique (remove duplicates)- final list of 10 items

3 (qset3)- Return extended lookup results for the 10 items

Open to another method if this one is going to be slow/inefficient.

For reference- my models are [here](http://dpaste.com/2ZZ336V).

```
class ProductListView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request
        user = User.objects.get(id=3)

        qset1 = (
            Product.objects
            .filter(variation__size__stock__stock__in=[1,2], store__appactive=True, store__region=user.settings_region, **filters)
            .filter(Q(gender=user.settings_gender) | Q(gender=3))
            .exclude(variation__analytic__user=user)
            .order_by('rating', '?')
            .value('pk',)
            )[:500]

        qset2 = (
            .distinct('pk')
            )[:10]
        )

        qset3 = (
            # READ PK's from QSET2
            .values('name', 'color', 'gender')
            .annotate(
                price=F('variation__price__price'),
            )[:10]
        )


        print str(qset.query)
        return Response(qset3)
```

Comment: qset2: make sure all the primary keys are unique? Primary keys are always unique by definition

Comment: Postgresql has very few limitations, you are doing a django orm query and even, then it's often possible to exploit the full power of postgresql

Comment: Please do post your models inline and explain what you really want to display.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of missing clues of Variations Model and the picture you have provided, but to get what you want, I guess you can apply the following:

```
class ProductListView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request
        user = User.objects.get(id=3)

        qset1 = Product.objects.filter(variation__size__stock__stock__in=[1, 2], 
                    store__appactive=True, store__region=user.settings_region, 
                    **filters)
                   .filter(Q(gender=user.settings_gender) | Q(gender=3))
                   .exclude(variation__analytic__user=user)
                   .order_by('rating', '?')
                   .annotate(price=F('variation__price__price'))
                   .distinct("pk")

        print str(qset1.query)
        return Response(qset1)
```

Now, if you see, the **`distinct("pk")`** will only apply distinct on the pk values. The later `distinct` will apply on the overall queryset of say 500 values that would be retrieved.